# Media Player Music Import

Tags: android, file-io

I'm trying to create a media player that sets all my songs in a playlist on my home screen. 
There are actually two things I cannot figure out. 1st one is, how can let the application update the playlist automatically from a folder in the android device. 
2nd Apparently, my application does not show me anything in the ListView I created for the playlist.

I tried to implement it using the following code:

```
           play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
           play.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
             // show interest in events resulting from ACTION_DOWN
             if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;
             // don't handle event unless its ACTION_UP so "doSomething()" only runs once.
             if(event.getAction()!=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;
            // doSomething();


             play.setPressed( !play.isPressed() );
             if(play.isPressed()==true){
                 //mp=MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this , R.raw.cia);
                 mp.start();}
             else {mp.stop();}
             return true;
            }
            });
```

I also created a function that updates my playlist, however, when I try to execute it, it gives me an error that unfortunately the program has stopped.

```
private void updatePlaylist(){ 
  File mus = new File(SD_PATH);
  if(mus.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0){
    for(File file : mus.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())){
        songs.add(file.getName());
    }

  ArrayAdapter<String> songList=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.song_item, songs);
  setListAdapter(songList);
 }
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use MediaStore. And you can use cursorAdapter as well.
From time to time it will update the playlist files in your device.

Here's an example:

```
// in your ListFragment
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // create adapter once
        Context context = getActivity();
        int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        null,
        null,
        null,
        MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
        int flags = 0; // no auto-requery
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, cursor, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, android.R.id.text1, flags);
    }

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
         setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

**UPD**

Here is a link about MediaStore: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html

And your FragmentList:

```
public class ContactsFragment extends ListFragment

{
    private static final String[] FROM = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE };
    private static final int[] TO = { android.R.id.text1 };
    private CursorAdapter mAdapter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.origin_lay, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Context context = getActivity();
        int layout = android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " ASC");
        int flags = 0; 
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(context, layout, cursor, FROM, TO, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState); 

        setListAdapter(mAdapter); 
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

In Activity just show this fragment.

Comment: I receive 3 errors at the "SimpleCursorAdapter"(constructor is undefined), at the "getActivity"(method undefined) and also at "setListAdapter(mAdapter)"(cannot be solved to a variable) . I'm just a beginner in android programming and I'm currently sort of learning by example, so can you please be more explicit?